# repeating 'to' here

Tags: prepositions

> It is this dedication to not only our school, but ***to*** the future
>   of legal education, that ensures our continued success.
>
> Being ready to respond to an emergency call comes down to not only
>   time, but ***to*** money management.

Is it grammatically wrong to repeat 'to' or is it just an option?

Comment: The construction really wants *too* or *also* or *as well*, and *not only* is in the wrong place to sustain the repetition: eg, "not only to X but [also] to Y".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few variations available here. Note the placement of **not only** and where **to** is used.

> It is this dedication **to** {*not only* our school *but* the future
>   of legal education...}  <sup>single prepositional phrase</sup>
>
> It is this dedication *not only* {**to** our school} *but* {**to** the
>   future of legal education ...} <sup>two prepositional phrases</sup>
>
> It is this dedication *not only* {**to** our school} *but also*
>   {**to** the future of legal education...}  <sup>two prep. phrases with **also**</sup>

I happen to think option 2 is the best, but concede that it's a matter of personal style.

However, the version you supplied doesn't work because of the placement of **not only** inside the prepositional phrase, in which case there should be only one prepositional phrase, not two:

> It is this dedication **to** *not only* our school, but **to** the
>   future of legal education, that ensures our continued success. <sup>flub</sup>